# Using MouseEvent with an extended JButton Class

Tags: java, inheritance, mouseevent

I have extended a JButton class to create a new class Btn. This was done to store corresponding x and y coordinates that are needed later on. My question is how do I get the X and Y coordinate when the button is pressed via the mouseEntered event?

```
public class Btn extends JButton{ 
private int x,y;
private JButton button;
public Btn(int x, int y,JButton button){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.button = buttton;
}
public int getBtnX{return x}
public int getBtnY{return y}
public JButton getBtnY{return button}
}

public class ButtonBox extends JFrame implements MouseListener{ 
Btn buttons[][] = new Btn[10][10];
private JButton initBtn(){
// set up button
}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
((Btn) e.getSource()).getBtnX // the x and y are need to get the coordiante to the button on the grid 
}
private setUpBtnBox(){
for(int i=0;i<buttons.length-1;i++ ){
for(int j=0;j<buttons.length-1;j++){
button[][] = new Btn(i,j,initBtn());
}
}
}
}
```

I tried both `((Btn) e.getSource()).getBtnX` and `((JButton) e.getSource()).getBtnX` to no avail. Is there a way to get the x and y using this method?

Comment: `((Btn) e.getSource()).getBtnX()` should do - but from your code sample there seems to be some confusion whether you want to extend JButton (then why do pass in another JButton instance?) or if you want to delegate to the passed button. Note that all JComponents have a `putClientProperty` method, which you might want want to (ab)use to store your extra coordinates.

Comment: @GyroGearless. Thank you for telling me about `putClientProperty` that looks like a really useful.  I went back an tried what I had before and again i am  still getting this error: 
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.desktop/javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to com.BattleShips.Btn`